# Concatenar set dateadd en un consulta de Sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

Tengo esta esta función en mi query de sql server que me coloca un día en especifico fijo y me suma 1 mes a mi mes actual

```
DECLARE @FEc DATETIME
SET @FEc = DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),102))
SET @FEc = DATEADD(DAY,(3-DATEPART(DD,@FECHA)),@FECHA)
SELECT @FEc

devuelve = 2020-07-15
```

me gusta que no tenga que declarar la variable si no, que en mi consulta ya este todo esto agregado con una etiqueta ejemplo

```
`SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),102))` as fecha 
   devuelve = 2020-07-06
```

(aquí solo me sumaria un mes pero no me traería el día que quiero como podría concatenar los dos , y disculpen esta función DATEADD(DAY,(3-DATEPART(DD,@FECHA)),@FECHA) la conseguí en un post y me funciona pero no la comprendo me podrían ayudar a entenderla

Comment: Sorry, no logro entender lo que estás buscando, puedes aclarar la pregunta?

Comment: necesito que lo que esta dentro de los dos SET funcione como uno solo dentro del select

Comment: ¿`@FECHA` de dónde viene? Por otro lado entiendo mas o menos lo que buscas, pero, tal vez no sea la solución adecuada, sino más bien resolver como es que quieres que sea el calculo de esta fecha,